# I don't know why the output is 30 and NaN

Tags: javascript

```js
let temp = {
  a: 10,
  b: 20,
  sum() {
    return this.a + this.b;
  },
  multi: () => {
    return this.a * this.b;
  },
};

console.log(temp.sum())
console.log(temp.multi())
```

I am beginner is JavaScript. I want to ask why the output of the code is

```
30 and NaN
```

Comment: You should read about [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), I am sure, your doubt will be clear

Answer (score 3):

Syntax is wrong, use

```
multi: function() {
    return this.a * this.b;
}
```

in the object.

**Edit**

The reason the arrow function [=>()] gives an error is because it does not recognize `this` as the context of the object it is called on but, in this case, the global context. Hence this result.

```js
var a=2, b=5;
let temp = {
  a: 10,
  b: 20,
  sum() {
    return this.a + this.b;
  },
  multi: () => {
    return this.a * this.b;
  },
};

console.log(temp.sum());
console.log(temp.multi());
```

Comment: This answer would be of more benefit if you explained why using `function() {}` instead of an arrow function resolves the issue

Comment: Explained in the edit. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is returning `NaN` when calling `multi()` is because of the peculiarity of the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#arrow_functions) keyword. The `this` in the `multi` function is not referring to the `temp` object as you might expect but instead referring to the global `this`. Run the following code to see the specific values being used in `multi`:

```js
let temp = {
  a: 10,
  b: 20,
  sum() {
    console.log('running `sum`:', 'this === window?', this === window);
    console.log(this.a, this.b, this.a + this.b);
    return this.a + this.b;
  },
  multi: () => {
    console.log('running `multi`:', 'this === window?', this === window);
    console.log(this.a, this.b, this.a * this.b);
    return this.a * this.b;
  }
};

console.log(temp.sum());
console.log(temp.multi());
```

In order to resolve it in `multi`, call the properties of `temp` instead of `this` (or change the signature of multi to be `multi() {` as `sum` is):

```js
let temp = {
  a: 10,
  b: 20,
  sum() {
    console.log('running `sum`:', 'this === window?', this === window);
    console.log(this.a, this.b, this.a + this.b);
    return this.a + this.b;
  },
  multi: () => {
    console.log('running `multi`:', 'temp === window?', temp === window);
    console.log(temp.a, temp.b, temp.a * temp.b);
    return temp.a * temp.b;
  }
};

console.log(temp.sum());
console.log(temp.multi());
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrow function expressions should not be used as methods as they do not have their own bindings to this according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). It is called "lexical this". Normally, traditional functions bind "this" to the object (hence this.a means 10). If you use "this" in arrow function, it would mean the global object 'Window'. Therefore, it became undefined * undefined which is NaN.